# How to specify date interval?

Tags: c#, log4net, rollingfileappender

I want to use RollingMode.Date to log by date. But default interval is one minute. I looked into source and saw, that class has protected enum RollPoint

```
/// <summary>
/// The code assumes that the following 'time' constants are in a increasing sequence.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// <para>
/// The code assumes that the following 'time' constants are in a increasing sequence.
/// </para>
/// </remarks>
protected enum RollPoint
{
    InvalidRollPoint = -1,
    TopOfMinute,
    TopOfHour,
    HalfDay,
    TopOfDay,
    TopOfWeek,
    TopOfMonth
}
```

How to specify RollPoint to RollingFileAppender object?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `datePattern` property of log configuration.

> To change the rolling period adjust the DatePattern value. For example, a date pattern of "yyyyMMdd" will roll every day. See System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo for a list of available patterns.

It narrows down to adding

```
<datePattern value="yyyyMMdd-HHmm" />
```

to your appender configuration. More information [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html).